# How come shared instances of apps from the app catalog only show the full page version of the app

Tags: sharepoint-addin, app, sharepoint-hosted-app

If I have an app that contains a full page Default.aspx and an App Part and share the app (Deployment UI) to a site collection from the app catalog how come only the full page of the app is available I dont see the app part as a selection to add to a page.

Only when the app is not shared and I add it directly to the site collection do I get the app part and the default.aspx.